# Getting mp3 file metadata

Tags: php, javascript, mp3, metadata, id3

I am a bit new to id3 tags and forgive me for the question is too basic.What's a quick and easy way to get **ALL** ID3 tags (artist, album, etc.) using php/javascript(client side preffered)?

I used this code but it ends up outputting nothing.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$tag = id3_get_tag( "lolwa.mp3" );
print_r($tag);
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

I know I have to include the ID3v2 library but am confused how exactly to include it.And will including it sove the problem of getting *all* ID3 tags like:

- bitrate
- comments
- duration etc.

Thanks a lot!

PS- I have included the mp3 file(lolwa.mp3) just next to my code(in the same folder).

PPS- Giving the absolute path of the mp3 file (    file:///C:/wamp/www/php/lolwa.mp3 in my case ) does not work either!

Comment: "And will including it solve the problem of getting all ID3 tags like: bitrate, comments, duration, etc" It will if these fields exist in ID3v2. But MP3 tracks with that info stored as tags are rare and like you already have seen, all players can get that info even if tags don't exist at all. To learn how read documentation of MP3 standard, especially part about info stored in file-header (how to calculate these values, how to get number of frames, bitrate, and rest of things you need to make calculation) That's certainly not an easy job, especially if track doesn't use constant-bitrate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the absolute path for getting mp3 data using `id3_get_tag()` function.

```
<?php
    $tag = id3_get_tag($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'lolwa.mp3'); 
    print_r($tag);
?>
```

Comment: can u please give absolute path for that mo3 file and not relative path.

Comment: Sorry please use $tag = id3_get_tag($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'lolwa.mp3');